# android mupdf, draw figure on the pdf page without using annotaion

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

How I can draw line or figure on pdf page without using annotation. If mupdf does not have this function then maybe other library you can advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the source code files for PDF viewer in Android application. Check the links and try it:

http://code.google.com/p/apv/source/browse/

http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/

http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/

http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/